# Managing own token cache crashing ios

Tags: iphone, facebook, caching, token, facebook-ios-sdk

I have followed the steps to manage my own token cache when a user logs in through Facebook on my app, however it always crashes when the login button is pressed. It calls:

```
NSDictionary *data = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:self.tokenFilePath];
```

and then crashes. If I change the initialisation of

```
_tokenFilePath = [self filePath];
```

to

```
self.tokenFilePath = [self filePath];
```

then it  doesn't crash, but then sometimes the login button has to be pressed multiple times before it logs in. 
How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: @Zaph No I'm not using ARC

Comment: Use ARC unless you have some compelling reason not to. With ARC both would work.

Comment: It was just an old project that I'm updating so was created before ARC existed. Thanks man, converted the project to ARC and it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using ARC there  is going to be a retain difference.

`self.tokenFilePath` calls a setter and that setter is increasing the retain count of `filePath`.

Without ARC assigning directly to an ivar does not increase the retain count.
Use:

```
_tokenFilePath = [[self filePath] retain];
```

With ARC the direct assignment increases the retain count.